# Excel 2007 if range = A2 vlookup

Tags: arrays, excel, search, match, vlookup

I want to know the month when the price of an item matching A2 was the lowest. how can I do a vlookup on only the items where column B = A2?

[image: example worksheet]

Comment: If you can sort the data on the Price column, Smallest to Largest, Then you could get the result with `=VLOOKUP(A2,B:F,5,FALSE)`, more so you could Set a `Brand` AdvancedFilter to the value in `A2` after sorting the Price column, and it would give you top results per brand as typed in also.

Comment: What is the result you want to get if there are several dates (with different months) that match the same lowest price?

Comment: And do you care about the item description (column D)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return month where price is lowest for product from `A2`, use this array formula (if there're more then one month with lowest price - formula will return first one):

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(MIN(IF(B:B=A2,E:E)),IF(B:B=A2,E:E),0))
```

note, since it's an array formula, you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it